# How can I deal with interference from a test RF signal (XM radio) in order to get a live RF signal of the same type?

Tags: rf, antenna

I'm located at a manufacturing plant where they have a test XM radio signal. I have a software engineering department located at the same plant that needs to work with a live XM signal.

The plant's test signal covers the whole block, so escaping from it would prove difficult. While discussing with some colleagues, building an open Faraday cage came up as a plausible theory for a solution.

Truth be told, I'm no EE, so I'm flying blind, but something tells me there should be a way to get a live XM signal from my position without having to use ultra-expensive equipment.

Is there a technique or principle that could let me get my live XM signal from my location?

Answer (score 1):

There are few possible measures you can take:
1. As suggested by pjc50, ask the manufacturing team to attenuate their test signal. They can use either a fixed attenuator or a variable one.
2. Install an XM band repeater at the software department. This is a more expansive solution. Sirius/XM offer one at http://shop.siriusxm.com/xm/ctl10600/cp49750/si4025848/cl1/ However, it is very likely that the repeater will capture the manufacturing floor's signal.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd keep the test signal in a Faraday cage. Or just connect it directly to antenna inputs on devices under test. Or turn the power down so it's only significant in the room it's needed in.

Comment: It sounds like the test signal may actually be violating FCC regulations.

Comment: I'm doubtful the OP is in the USA and under the authority of the FCC. More likely somewhere in the Far East.

Comment: Actually Mexico according to his profile.